# Why is the en-dash written as '\xe2\x80\x93' in Python?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

Specifically, what does each escape in `\xe2\x80\x93` do and why does it need 3 escapes? Trying to decode one by itself leads to an 'unexpected end of data' error.

```python
>>> print(b'\xe2\x80\x93'.decode('utf-8'))
–
>>> print(b'\xe2'.decode('utf-8'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: unexpected end of data
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have [UTF-8 bytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), which is a *codec*, a standard to represent text as computer-readable data. The [U+2013 EN-DASH codepoint](https://codepoints.net/U+2013) encodes to those 3 bytes when encoded to that codec.

Trying to decode just one such byte as UTF-8 doesn't work because in the UTF-8 standard that one byte does not, on its own, carry meaning. In the UTF-8 encoding scheme, a `\xe2` byte is used for all codepoints between U+2000 and U+2FFF in the Unicode standard (which would all be encoded with an additional 2 bytes); thats 4095 codepoints in all.

Python represents values in a `bytes` object in a manner that lets you reproduce the value by copying it back into a Python script or terminal. Anything that isn't printable ASCII is then represented by a `\xhh` hex escape. The two characters form the hexadecimal value of the byte, an integer number between 0 and 255.

Hexadecimal is a very helpful way to represent bytes because you can represent the 2 pairs of 4 bytes each with one character, a digit in the range 0 - F.

`\xe2\x80\x93` then means there are three bytes, with the hexadecimal values E2, 80 and 93, or 226, 128 and 147 in decimal, respectively. The UTF-8 standard tells a decoder to take the last 4 bits of the first byte, and the last 6 bytes of each of the second and third bytes (the remaining bits are used to signal what type of byte you are dealing with for error handling). Those 4 + 6 + 6 == 16 bits then encode the hex value 2013 (`0010 000000 010011` in binary).

You probably want to read up about the difference between codecs (encodings) and Unicode; UTF-8 is a codec that can handle all of the Unicode standard, but is not the same thing. See:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you clarify what the specific purpose of the `\xe2` escape is in Unicode? Does it indicate anything?

Comment: @minerz029: UTF-8 is not Unicode. It is a *codec*, but one that can handle all of the Unicode standard. `\xe2` is just a byte. If you decoded it with a different codec, then you'd get a different Unicode result. `\xe2` decoded as ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1) would give you the U+00E2 codepoint, or the `â` character (small latin a with circumflex).

Comment: @minerz029: to paraphrase Martijn, `\xe2` is a byte that does not have much meaning in itself, it's the first (4+)4 bits of some UTF8-encoded character between codepoints U+2000 and U+2FFF