# What's the difference of '\xe2\x80\x93' and '-' in python? How do I change all to the latter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, encode

I encountered error while writing data to bigquery with apache.beam pipeline (Field string_value encountered non-ASCII string '\xe2\x80\x93':'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2).

I get my data from a http request, and the response body contains "\xe2\x80\x93" instead of "–"(en-dash).

Quesion 1:
What's the difference of "\xe2\x80\x93" and "–"(en-dash), while their print are the same?

```
>>> a='\xe2\x80\x93'
>>> a
'\xe2\x80\x93'
>>> print a
–
>>> b='–'
>>> b
'–'
>>> print b
–
```

Question 2:
How can I change "\xe2\x80\x93" to "–"(en-dash)? The expected result is:

```
>>> a='\xe2\x80\x93'
>>> (some operation to a here)
>>> a
'–'
>>> print a
–
```

The reason why I want to do the change is I found that "–"(en-dash) can be written to bigquery successfully while "\xe2\x80\x93" throws the above error.

There're other characters having this problem, so I can't just replace "\xe2\x80\x93".

Thanks.

Comment: Your `-` (`b`) is a regular ASCII hyphen-minus. The other is an en-dash.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968179/why-is-the-en-dash-written-as-xe2-x80-x93-in-python. Sounds silly but why don't `if a == '\xe2\x80\x93': a = '-'`?

Comment: @deceze Thanks, but can I change "a" into an en-dash(string, not bytes)?

Comment: @SergioPulgarin Thanks, "\xe2\x80\x93" is just one of the cases, other characters could throw similar errors

Comment: I see, then I'd say follow up on that answer I posted and the links they provide, and do it the right way.

Answer (score 2):

`b"\xe2\x80\x93"` isn't ASCII; since ASCII is 7 bit, an obvious indicator is that all these bytes have the top bit set (values 128 and higher). It is UTF-8, and decodes as such to one character, code point 0x2013, which is an [en-dash](https://unicode-table.com/en/2013/). The [hyphen-minus](https://unicode-table.com/en/002D/) at 0x2d is a similar character that exists in ASCII, but replacing it is only an approximation. That said, such approximations are available in e.g. [`iconv`'s `ASCII//TRANSLIT` target](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv). `iconv` is not in the Python standard library, but is available as a module in PyPI.

It sounds like you are aware these should be en-dash; in that case, perhaps all you need is an `a.decode('UTF-8')` call to produce the proper unicode string.