# How to compare two strings of different encoding in python?

Tags: python, string, encoding, ctypes

Context:

I'm extracting a string from a txt file encoded in `'utf-8', application_name = 'MicrosoftEdge'`

Then I'm using python ctypes module to determine the current active application window = curr_application

```
user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)
curr_window = user32.GetForegroundWindow()
window_name = str(win32gui.GetWindowText(curr_window))
rev = window_name[::-1]
pos = rev.find("-")
curr_application = rev[0:pos][::-1].replace(" ","")
```

which also returns: `'MicrosoftEdge'`

but when I do:

```
print(curr_application == application_name)
```

it always returns `False`

Here's the output I got from:

```
>>> print(application_name.encode())
b'MicrosoftEdge\n'
>>> print(curr_application.encode())
b'Microsoft\xe2\x80\x8bEdge'
```

My question is, what should I do so that I get true when I compare both strings?

Comment: The two strings are not really identical the `\xe2\x80\x8b` is a `-` you can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57568020/whats-the-difference-of-xe2-x80-x93-and-in-python-how-do-i-change-all-t) with an explanation for that, but you'll have to handle those differences.

Comment: But when I print them without encode() there isn't any "-" in those strings

Comment: sorry you're right I missed the difference. That one is a `ZERO WIDTH SPACE`, so it is invisible. You can find it [here](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128&utf8=string-literal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

Here's what worked for me:

```
import string
allowed_chars = string.ascii_letters
application_name = 'MicrosoftEdge'
curr_application = 'Microsoft\xe2\x80\x8bEdge'
application = ""
for letter in curr_application:
    if letter in allowed_chars:
        application = application + letter
print(application==application_name)
```

which then returns **True**

Answer (score 0):

You can remove that character by replacing it with the empty string:

```py
curr_application.replace('\N{ZERO WIDTH SPACE}', '')
```