# Python XML Parse errors with Invalid Token

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, minidom

I am moving code from Python 2.7 to Python 3.10.  One section of the code creates XML which is 'prettyfied' and written to a file.  But parsing in Python 3.x is throwing an error.
In one case the problem seems to be with an encoded en-dash character.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf8'?>
<properties>
    <entry key="name">AB&amp;R - RFA #3 \xe2\x80\x93 Alignment</entry>
</properties>
```

The parsing is done as follows:

```
xml_parsed = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(xml_string)
return xml_parsed.toprettyxml("    ", "\n")
```

The error thrown is:

```
not well-formed (invalid token): line 2
```

I don't think this problem happened with Python 2.7.
[There is a nice description about en-dash here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968179/why-is-the-en-dash-written-as-xe2-x80-x93-in-python) (although I think my problem is not limited to en-dash).

What can be done to fix this?

Comment: I do not get this error with Python 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

My original description of the problem was not right.
The XML text was stored as a byte string.
The following code worked for me:

```
    xml_string = xml_string.decode("utf-8")
    xml_parsed = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(xml_string)
    return xml_parsed.toprettyxml("    ", "\n")
```

I didn't need to do the utf-8 decode in Python 2.7.